# Tufte running headers not using full width of page

Tags: xetex, header-footer, fontspec, tufte

I use Minion Pro and XeLaTeX together with the tufte class. There is an issue with caps in headers (as can be noticed if removing the two line marked `%% headings fixes` below). My fix is to use the `myheadings` option – but I get a strange effect where the running headers only use up the main text block width and not the full width (the main block + sidenotes).

```
\documentclass[nols]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\title{Example of tufte headings problem}
\author{Author}

%% headings fixes
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{\textsc{example of tufte headings problem}}{\textsc{example of tufte headings problem}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{First section}

First section body.

\newpage

Second page.

\newpage

Notice how the headings only uses the main text block width and not the full width of the page.

\end{document}
```

What could be a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tufte uses [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) for headings, and your work-around is clobbering it. If you want to redefine the header manually, use the `fancyhdr` way of doing it (using `\fancyhead`).

But there is a better way anyway.

The root cause of your difficulty is that when loaded with XeLaTeX, the `tufte` class does not know how to construct its `\smallcaps` and `\allcaps` macros, which produce spaced small and large capitals. It's `\smallcaps` that is used in the heading, which is what produces your problem.

I think the better way to achieve what you want is to get those working, using `fontspec`. The following seems to work

```
\renewcommand\smallcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace = 8}\scshape#1}}
\renewcommand\allcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace = 15}#1}}
```

You can then dispense with your workaround. The side-effect is that (as the class wants, and as is good practice) your capitals and small caps are spaced, and `\allcaps` and `\smallcaps` will work as they should. If you find the space too great, reduce the `LetterSpace` number somewhat. I aimed for numbers that I thought roughly matched the `tufte` figures.

Comment: That's great. Since I had a very long title I then used the optional short title for `\title` : `\title[Short title]{Long … … title}`– it works as I intended.

Comment: I guess this should be fixed in the tufte-class, to work with XeLaTeX – but that´s for another forum…