# Force all small caps

Tags: capitalization, small-caps

Is it possible to force text into lower case small caps without making capital letters lower case?

None of the following makes all the letters lower case small caps:

```
\textsc{Can I make this line only small caps?}
\scshape{Can I make this line only small caps?}
```

To get all small caps one needs to format it manually to lower case:

```
\textsc{can i make this line only small caps?}
```

Update:

As @barbarabeeton has pointed out `\sc`is deprecated so I have removed that example.

Comment: perhaps `\lowercase{\scshape WhAtEvEr text}`, since otherwise uppercase letters will remain uppercase.  but both `\sc` (which is deprecated in latex) and `\scshape` should be placed *inside* the group since they are global directives rather than commands taking an argument.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That seems like a good solution. Thank you for the heads up regarding the deprecated `\sc` – I just saw that it affects the entire group as well.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\textlcsc{An ExaMple}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option would be to use `\MakeTextLowercase` from the `textcase` package:

```
\usepackage{textcase}
\newcommand\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
```

Comment: So, I wonder which of this or Barbara's is the best one. I would prefer an even shorter solution – but I guess I should create a new command then…

Comment: +1 If this is related to the `tufte-latex` class and [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114578/tufte-running-headers-not-using-full-width-of-page), you might note that the `\smallcaps` command is there defined as `\smallcapsspacing{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}`, where `\smallcapspacing` produces spaced small capitals, so exactly as Gonzalo Medina suggests.

Comment: @trmdttr `\lowercase` works only on plain ASCII characters, while `\MakeLowercase` is smarter.

Comment: @trmdttr I changed the example to include a command; I used `\MakeLowercase` since \lowercase is a TeX command which doesn't always work.

Comment: @PaulStanley Oh, I see – then that solves it! You're all a very helpful bunch.